# Salesforce Apex invoke Save on Edit page using PageReference

Tags: salesforce, apex

The functionality I have written works, this is for a test method.

In apex test code, I create a StandardController then a controller extension and invoke a method on that controller extension which returns a PageReference to a custom object's standard edit page. I want to change field values on that edit page and invoke the Save method/button, is this possible and how?

In advance, thanks.

Comment: Please, add peaces of your code to the question

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot change values in a standard edit screen from within a test method, nor do you need to.  The correct way to test logic that is executed after saving on a standard edit screen is to construct an instance of a new record, populate the fields, and insert it into the database.

Comment: I'm not testing the logic that executes after a save, I'm using the Edit page, with fields prepopulated from url parameters, that still requires some user input for other fields, in order to then save, so that it then inserts a new record. What I'm testing is the successful insertion of that record, and subsequently the successful prepopulation of its fields.

Comment: You can't really write test methods for that, as Salesforce considers it to be a standard functionality.  You could try generating the URL with all params and then using Test.setCurrentPage() and see if you can scrape the body to confirm the results.